# Call to possibly undefined method dispatchEvent through a reference with static type GetColor

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dispatchevent

I'm writing a program using Main.as, that needs to listen to a function (getColor) in another class file (GetColor.as). I have the following in GetColor.as:

```
public class GetColor
{
  public function getColor(event:MouseEvent):void
  {
    //doing stuff here
    this.dispatchEvent(new Event("changeColor") );
  }
}
```

and then in Main.as I have:

```
var getPicColor:GetColor = new GetColor();
getPicColor.addEventListener("changeColor",changeColorNow);
function changeColorNow(e:Event):void
{
  //do stuff here
}
```

However, I am getting an error:

```
1061: Call to a possibly undefined method dispatchEvent through a reference
with static type GetColor.
```

What does this mean? I have nothing declared as static. Am I supposed to create an instance of dispatchEvent(), as opposed to using "this"?

Comment: Try: `public class GetColor extends  EventDispatcher`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dispatch events with a class that (implicitly) extends `Object` -> that's why you are getting there error -> where is "dispatchEvent()" method coming from? Where is it inherited from? (answer: it is not!)

Your `GetColor` class (horrible name there! :) ) must either extend a display object - which in your case it not really the correct solution, extend `EventDispatcher` or implement `IEventDispatcher`.

Then you can use the method `dispatchEvent`.

Comment: If GetColor is something like a color picker component extending a `DisplayObject` can be a correct solution.